# Cannot display the correct output using setw(20)

Tags: c++

Here is my code. I tried all the different ways with left `<< setw(20)` but it does not show me the proper outcome.

```
void MotorVehicle::moveTo(const char* address)
    {
        if (strcmp(Address, address) != 0)
        {
            cout << "|" << setw(10) << PlateNumber << "| |" << setw(20) << Address << " --->--- ";
            cout << address << "|" << endl;
            strcpy(Address, address);
        }
    }
```

Hi guys this is the expected out put.

```
|    T-1111| |            Montreal --->--- New York            |
|    T-1111| |            New York --->--- New Jersey          |
|    T-1111| |            New Jersey --->--- Toronto           |
```

Comment: Can you show what you do get? Also might be worth showing what's in your variables (it seems obvious, but mistakes can lie in the obvious).

Comment: class MotorVehicle
 {
 private:
  char PlateNumber[MAX_PLATE + 1];
  char Address[MAX_ADDRESS + 1];
  int Year;

Comment: ----------------------------------------
|> T1: Vehicle
----------------------------------------
| 2010 | VVV-111 | Factory

|   VVV-111| |             Factory --->--- Downtown Toronto|
|   VVV-111| |    Downtown Toronto --->--- Mississauga|
|   VVV-111| |         Mississauga --->--- North York|

Comment: Put this sort of thing as an edit to the question. The formatting for comments just isn't up to the job.

Answer (score 2):

Remember `setw` is not 'sticky'. It only applies to the subsequent output field. All other manipulators apply until the are superseded.

Thus I think you want:

```
 cout << setw(20) << left << address << "|" << endl;
```